# Getting combination Percentages in r

Tags: r

Relatively new to R and very new here in stackoverflow.

I'm trying to analyze .csv output files from a microscope.

The output will tell me whether each cell on the image is "positive" (expressed with a 1) or "negative" (with a 0)

`my_data <- data.frame(cell = 1:4, marker_a = c(1, 0, 0, 0), marker_b = c(0,1,1,1), marker_c = c(0,1,1,0))`

Sometimes we measure 4 markers, sometimes more.

I already wrote something that gives me a vector with the "used markers" and discards the "unused markers" (in this case it would be marker e,f, g which also show up in the .csv file).

I want to automatically get all the possible combinations that a cell can take.

A cell can be 0 for all markers, or can be positive for `marker_a` but negative for `marker_b`,`marker_c`,`marker_d`.

My end goal is to quantify all the cells that fall under each category/combination.

I would want a vector that would name each possible combination from all markers with a 0 value, to all of them wiht a 1 value.

What I have been doing so far is manually generating the combinations.

`no_marker <- my_data$marker_a == 0 & my_data$marker_b == 0 & my_data$marker_c == 0`
`a_positive <- my_data$marker_a == 1 & my_data$marker_b == 0 & my_data$marker_c == 0...`

Then I can just create a data.frame to add more samples later.

`cell_phenotypes <- c("no_marker", "a_positive", "ab_positive", "abc_positive", "abcd_positive", "b_ positive", "bc_positive"...)`

I just don't want to manually create the vector every time.

Comment: Could you please share your expected result for this sample dataset.

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow!  It would help clarify if you provided the desired output from your example data.  And right now it's hard to work on the same data you describe; could you edit it to be runnable, e.g., `my_data <- data.frame(cell = 1:4, marker_a = c(1, 0, 0, 0) ...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want `expand.grid`.

```
expand.grid(
    marker_a = c(0, 1), 
    marker_b = c(0, 1), 
    marker_c = c(0, 1), 
    marker_d = c(0, 1)
)

#>    marker_a marker_b marker_c marker_d
#> 1         0        0        0        0
#> 2         1        0        0        0
#> 3         0        1        0        0
#> 4         1        1        0        0
#> 5         0        0        1        0
#> 6         1        0        1        0
#> 7         0        1        1        0
#> 8         1        1        1        0
#> 9         0        0        0        1
#> 10        1        0        0        1
#> 11        0        1        0        1
#> 12        1        1        0        1
#> 13        0        0        1        1
#> 14        1        0        1        1
#> 15        0        1        1        1
#> 16        1        1        1        1
```

Note that 16 is the right number; you can check since `2**4 = 16`.

Comment: I think this will really help! I was not familiar with this function. Any tips on how to use this with the original data to come up with the total number of cells meeting these 16 conditions?